# use of abstract as enumerated type?

Tags: enums, haxe

I am looking at the following Haxe source code from the "Pattern Matching - Array Matching" example at [try.haxe.org](http://try.haxe.org/) -

```
class Test {

    static function main() {
        var playerA = {
            name: "Simn",
            move: Move.Paper
        }
        var playerB = {
            name: "Nicolas",
            move: Move.Rock
        }

        // a switch can directly return something
        var winner = switch ([playerA.move, playerB.move])      {
            case [Move.Rock, Move.Paper]: playerB;
            case [Move.Scissors, Move.Paper]: playerA;
            default: null;
        }

        if (winner != null)         {
            trace('The winner is: ${winner.name}');
        }           else            {
            trace('Draw!');
        }
    }
}   

@:enum
abstract Move(Int)     {
    var Rock = 1;
    var Paper = 2;
    var Scissors = 3;
}
```

my questions are:

1. what does the notation `@:enum` signify?
2. Why did they create the enumerated type this way instead of simply doing:

   enum Move
   {
       Rock;
       Paper;
       Scissors;
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @enum metadata informs the compiler to treat an abstract class as an enumeration. The main advantage is to be able to define values to each constant.

In the case of the example, the array [Move.Rock, Move.Paper] would be the same as [1,2] but the compiler will ensure that each value comes from the enum type.

You can find more here
http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-enum.html